# Is my old phone still recoverable after super bricking it?

Tags: unbricking

A long time ago, when I was way dumber, I really wanted to upgrade my old phone (Wiko Lenny 3) from Android 6.0 to Android 7.0 but with no avail. Since that day, the phone is no longer bootable. If I try to connect my phone with the computer, it won't even detect it. I tried every way to fix the full issue.

What I mean with "super bricked phone" is that I tried to install another phone's system (Wiko Lenny 4 probably, can't remember) into the main phone, which lead to the complete brick that the kernel, system, boot, preloader and such stuff are corrupted. Now I know that I can buy another motherboard and install it into Wiko Lenny 3, but I don't want to waste that much of my money for something that I completely rigged.

If there is any other way to fix this issue, then I could try without making more damage to the Wiko Lenny 3 phone.

**Edit 1:**

I tried to find the KCOLO/KOLO/COLO point, that I need to short with the GND golden point, but I literally can't find the KOLO point. This device has 2 GND points, so with this, I don't know which I need to short. I provide an image to it
[image: The Wiko Lenny 3 motherboard / main board]

Comment: https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-11802.html

Comment: I don't know if it will succeed, but I trust this site.

Comment: i really have no clue but i have seen somewhere that SCL might be the kcol0 test point. i believe it's the first point near the touch screen connector https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUYMk0C4ylY

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/can-someone-help-me-with-this-bricked-phone.3308769 btw i recommend NOT to soldering any wires to the PCB. just puncture with some needles